# problem binding to filtered dataview

Tags: asp.net

I'm having a problem with the dtaview.  I'm dynamically creating new datacolumns, assigning  them values, and adding them into my datatable.  Before using a filter, this was fine when binding.  All values appeared.

However, I have since chosen to reduce returned results by filtering (by letter), and my returned dataview doesn't seem to allow binding with the newly created data columns.  I've mined into the filtered view, and can see that the values are present that I need.

I'm trying to avoid putting everything back into a table again after applying the filter.  An sql query based on letter is out of the question, as the whole original table is sitting in view state.

Here are some code snippets:

```
        --Firstly create new datacolumn

        Dim ICount As System.Data.DataColumn = New System.Data.DataColumn
        ICount.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
        ICount.AllowDBNull = True
        ICount.ColumnName = "ICount"
        register.Columns.Add(ICount)

        --integer value is first calculated and then put into the datatable row

        row("ICount") = IntegerCount.ToString()

        --filtered view is created from datatable (returned from viewstate)

        Dim filteredView As New Data.DataView(pTable, FilterExpression, "Surname", Data.DataViewRowState.OriginalRows)

         --view is bound

         grd.DataSource = filteredView
         grd.DataBind()

         --Markup

         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="ICount" SortExpression="ICount">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="IC" runat="server"                     Text='<%# Bind("ICount") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

All of the non dynamic datacolumns are fine.  Mining into both the datatable and the filtered view show values are there.

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - fixed this.

The problem was that I wasn't using the dataset.

So instead of creating a new view, I should have done the following:

datTable = CType(ViewState("datTable"), System.Data.DataTable)

datSet.Tables.Add(datTable)

datView = datSet.Tables(0).DefaultView

datView.RowFilter = FilterExpression

grd.DataSource = datView

grd.DataBind()

All values are now coming through.